# SQL insert into table from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let say I have a table: `table3` and I want to insert values from `table1` and `table2` into `table3`

`table1`: Columns: `hID` `hName`
`table2`: Columns: `aID` `aName`
`table3`: Columns: `hID` `aID`

I want to insert table1 `hID` and table2 `aID` into table3 How would I do that?

my current query uses an inner join to attempt to join table1 and table2 but table1 and table2 don't share a common column, so how do I this?

my query:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (hID, aID)
SELECT hID
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON ??;
```

Comment: If table1 has 10 rows and table2 has 15 rows how would the result look?

Comment: Is there any specific criteria to match a row from table1 against table2, or you just want to match any row from the left with any row from the right?

Comment: the latter, any match

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather artificial since relational databases rarely join tables in this manner. It is, however, possible to do so, even with uneven data sets. You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate an mock value that you can use to join both tables.

For example:

```
with
l as (select hID, row_number() over() as rn from table1),
r as (select aID, row_number() over() as rn from table2)
select l.hID, r.aID from l left join r on r.rn = l.rn
union
select l.hID, r.aID from l right join r on r.rn = l.rn
```

If the left values are 1, 2, 3, 5, and 7, and the right values are 101, 200, and 555, the result it produces is (in no particular order):

```
 hID  aID  
 ---- ---- 
 1    101  
 2    220  
 3    555  
 5    null 
 7    null
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xf8d42JAbNkFmHDEm6eZbc/0).

**Note**: The query could be simpler if MySQL implemented `FULL JOIN`. Unfortunately it doesn't so it needs to be simulated.